# How can I color a cell based on character capitalization?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a list of text values I want to show as a drop down menu, which is mentioned below.

If the value contains capital letters, I want the cell to be colored blue. On uncapitalized letters, I want to use a yellow shading.

I have tried many things, but was unable to get what I want. Can I use conditional formatting to recognize the difference between small and capital letters?

`{d;D;EZ;F;f;g;G;s;S;SU;U;u}`

Comment: your example is not clear.

Comment: {d;D;EZ;F;f;g;G;s;S;SU;U;u} this text I want to use in drop down list with color effect. As you can see d and D, there is a difference in the meaning of both. I want to use different colors for the both

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of this example, I have assumed your dropdown list to be located in cell `A1`. Make sure to edit the formulas to fit your needs.

Go to conditional formatting and create three rules:

1. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, enter`=EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1))` and format the cell with blue fill color.
2. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, enter`=EXACT(A1,LOWER(A1))` and format the cell with yellow fill color.
3. Select `Format only cells that contain`. Under "Format only cells with:" select `Blanks`. There will be no need to change the formatting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to select the column in the excel sheet before I enter the formula and apply it.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create the drop down list**

- Select the cell where the drop down menu should be placed.
- On the Data ribbon tab click 'Data Validation'.
- Select Allow: List
- Enter your text values at Source: without the curly brackets. The separator can differ from your localization. Standard english computers are using the comma as the separator. On my German machine, I have to use a semicolon.
- Click OK. Your cell now has a fancy drop down button on the right.

**2. Conditional formatting**

- Select the cell containing the drop down list
- On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
- Select 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'
- At 'Format values where this formula is true:' enter this formula:

  ```
  =CODE(A1)<=90
  ```
- Click format and select a blue cell shading.
- Repeat the last steps to enter the formula for the yellow shading:

  ```
  =CODE(A1)>=97
  ```
- Click format and select a yellow cell shading.

Pay attention that you have to change A1 to the actual location of your drop down cell.

Comment: Thanks alot, the formula is working fine for captial letters but unfortunately not for small letters

Comment: Select the drop down cell and click Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules. Check that there is no mistake, especially at the 'Applies to' section. Click Edit Rule... to have a look at the formula again. 

If you're missing the second rule, then chances are that something went wrong. Use 'Show formatting rules for: This Worksheet' and correct the mistake.

Comment: I am getting problem in apply to section. Otherwise the formula is working perfect.

Comment: when i apply to single column its owrking but not wokring with selecting many cells

Comment: or for ever cell I have to write the formula?

Comment: @Mani When applying a conditional format to multiple cells, you must set the cell reference in the formula to the top left cell. For example: If you want to format C5:F10, you must use =CODE(C5)<=90. Don't use something like =CODE(A5), =CODE(F10) or even =CODE($C$5), the latter would 'pin' the cell. Imagine that Excel walks trough all the cells you've specified in 'Applies to', beginning top left. It changes the formula according to the cell it is currently formatting.